# Add CSS class to entity reference (taxonomy type) rendered as a field in a node

Tags: theming, entities, taxonomy-terms

This is my first question on the forum. I am currently developing a site (Drupal 8.8.1). I am developing it in a sub directory on the server and not using Drush, the server belongs to a large academic institution and they do not give me access to set up a localhost. I have a good understanding of HTML and CSS, but only the very basics of PHP.

I have a very specific theming issue I need some help with. I have a taxonomy vocabulary (a list of authors) which is displayed using entity reference (label format - link to ref entity) as a field which appears on certain nodes and views. This renders the author's name as a link that links to all other instances of that same author. This is fine, but I need to make some of the terms of this vocabulary not appear or function as a link.

The rendered HTML for the specific field I am interested in looks like this:

```
<div class="field--item"><a href="/__D8/taxonomy/term/9" hreflang="en">AUTHOR'S NAME</a></div>
```

What I need is to do is to be able to remove the href from the anchor tag on specific taxonomy terms and add something like class="{{ name }}", or somehow get the taxonomy term ID to determine its CSS class attribute. I have tried to do this by overriding the taxonomy-term.html.twig and the field.html.twig (renaming it to specifically target my field: field--node--field-researchers--publications.html.twig). I put these two files in my MYTHEME/templates directory and disabled Views Taxonomy Term view, but I cannot make the class tag appear.

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to get the effect I want, but I can't think of another way at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.